# What's a url-friendly way to pass a long mixed string variable from javascript into a GET url variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, get

I've inherited a project with a simple AJAX GET handler for mostly simple `name`, `value` pairs of simple variables (i.e. `?type=new&id=4`).  But now I need to pass a small paragraph sized text string that can include all sorts of funny characters.  Typically I'd POST this type of variable, but right now its a corner case and I'd rather not rewrite the entire AJAX server side handler.

Given these constraints, what would you recommend?

Sample string to pass:

```
Lorem ipsum! Dolor=sit&amet, `consectetur` "adipiscing 'elit'." Sed sollicitudin lorem justo, in vulputate nulla eleifen. Duis est rhoncus.
```

I can encode it anyway I want via JavaScript, so long as it can be decoded later on by PHP.

What do you recommend?

Ultimately it needs to be in a url like so:

```
/ajax-get-handler.php?string=[insert best practice encoded string here]
```

Comment: re-write the entire AJAX server-side handler?  you mean, replacing the $_GET['variable'] with $_POST['variable']?  And can't forget changing the $.ajax method to post.  It's never good practice to allow a URL to look like it came from doubleclick.net in 1999.

Comment: Hahaha. Well rewriting to POST would involve touching every other script. The laziest option would be to use `$_REQUEST['var']`. But I'd like to see how this goes first. +1 for doubleclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you coulld try [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), like

```
"string=" + encodeURIComponent("your-long-text-here");
```

Comment: Thanks. A quick google led me to see that it's decoded on the php side with `$jsonStr = stripslashes($_GET['string']); $json = json_decode ($jsonStr);` Does that sound about right to you?

Comment: @Ryan on PHP side you can use rawurldecode() for decoding the parameters